# What is causing my Canvas element to overflow and what can I do to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have a problem with sizing my canvas element properly. The result as seen below is a canvas element (green outline) that extends it's height outside of it's parent div. What is causing this problem and what can I do to fix it?

[image: resulting]

**HTML:** Here is the HTML code, there isn't much to it.

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="menu">
            ...
        </div>
        <div id="canvas-container">
            <canvas>
    
            </canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS:** The more interesting SCSS code.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif,
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    #content {
        outline: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
        width: 80%;
        height: 80%;

        #menu {
            padding: 1em;
            border-bottom: 2px solid black;

            select {
                padding: 1em;
            }

            a {
                background-color: rgb(91, 134, 195);
                text-decoration: none;
                font-weight: bold;
                padding: 0.8em;
                color: white;
            }

            a:hover {
                background-color: rgb(75, 122, 189);
            }

        }

        #canvas-container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;

            canvas {
                outline: 2px solid green;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Javascript:** And lastly the JS code that actually does the sizing of the Canvas element.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
fitToContainer(canvas);

function fitToContainer(canvas){
  // Make it visually fill the positioned parent
  canvas.style.width ='100%';
  canvas.style.height='100%';
  // ...then set the internal size to match
  canvas.width  = canvas.offsetWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using JS to resize the canvas instead of css?

Comment: Your content will need a `position: relative` otherwise 100% height is the next element up.  Looking at your layout, I would also say flexbox wound not go miss.

Comment: @ArchitGargi I am not experienced with using the Canvas element and based on some reading I've done it is often necessary to have a resize/fit function in JS to properly set the dimensions of the Canvas so to display the contents of it properly. Therefore I am trying to handle all sizing of the canvas in JS instead of CSS.

Comment: @ArchitGargi  Because CSS will effect the visual size of the canvas, but not the canvas size..

Comment: @Keith I tried your tip by putting that position on first only `content`, then only `canvas-container` and lastly on both, but no apparent change has taken place.

Comment: @NoName123  Yes, that's why I said your going to also want a flexbox.  I'll see if I can knock up a simple example.

Comment: More on flexbox here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Comment: @Keith Alright, I'll hang tight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use a height of 100% and you want the height based on it's parent, you need to set the parents position to relative.

Also the layout your using looks like it will fit into a flexbox layout nicely.

Lastly, if you want this to be responsive, your going to want to attach a resize event for setting the canvas size.

Below is an example of using these techniques, I've also included a footer section, flexbox makes these layout a breeze.  hint: run the snippet fullscreen, and resize the window to see the resizing in action.

```js
const c = document.querySelector('canvas');
const cc = document.querySelector('.canvas-container');

function drawSomething() {
  const ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  const w = c.offsetWidth; h = c.offsetHeight;
  const cnt = 25;
  const sw = w / cnt; sh = h / cnt;
  for (let l = 0; l <= cnt; l ++) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, l * sh);
    ctx.lineTo(w - l * sw, 0);
    ctx.moveTo(w, l * sh);
    ctx.lineTo(l * sw, 0);
    ctx.moveTo(0, l * sh);
    ctx.lineTo(w - l * sw, h);
    ctx.moveTo(w, l * sh);
    ctx.lineTo(l * sw, h);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}

function resize() {
  c.width  = cc.offsetWidth;
  c.height = cc.offsetHeight;
  drawSomething(); 
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
resize();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header, .footer {
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
}


.canvas-container {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}

canvas {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">This is the menu</div>
  <div class="canvas-container">
    <canvas></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#container 
    #content {
        outline: 2px solid #000;
        width: 80%;
        height: 80%;
        >> display: flex;
        >> flex-direction: column;
    }
```

Comment: Oh right, I forgot to add that. With this addition I get [this](https://imgur.com/a/41zCRBO) (opens imgur link) result. As we can see there's still overflow.

Comment: @NoName123 [Here](https://gist.github.com/kstrub/153b058382cc9669aec2227adcb69f51) is the complete code I used. Works over here. I Compiled your scss to css to make it work in one html file.

Answer (score 0):

```
here is you add in css  `#container{height:100%}` you can replace `height:100%;` to "`min-height:100%;`"
```

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
fitToContainer(canvas);

function fitToContainer(canvas) {
  // Make it visually fill the positioned parent
  canvas.style.width = "100%";
  canvas.style.height = "100%";
  // ...then set the internal size to match
  canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
}
```

```css
* {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
 html, body {
     height: 100%;
     font-size: 16px;
     font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
}
 #container {
     min-height: 100%;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
}
 #container #content {
     outline: 2px solid #000;
     width: 80%;
     height: 80%;
}
 #container #content #menu {
     padding: 1em;
     border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
 #container #content #menu select {
     padding: 1em;
}
 #container #content #menu a {
     background-color: #5b86c3;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding: 0.8em;
     color: white;
}
 #container #content #menu a:hover {
     background-color: #4b7abd;
}
 #container #content #canvas-container {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
 #container #content #canvas-container canvas {
     outline: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="menu">
      ...
    </div>
    <div id="canvas-container">
      <canvas>

      </canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding `html {overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y:hidden;}` to your SCSS to stop the overflow

Comment: Canvas is not overflowing the page but only the parent container.